# How to merge the value of a Subject "next" into the main stream with Rxjs

Tags: rxjs

The method **retryWhen** returns a **Subject**, how can I merge it's next value with the main stream ?

```
dataStream.
    retryWhen(errors => {
        return errors.
            delay(1000).
            take(3).
            concat(Rx.Observable.throw(errors));
    }).
    subscribe(
        x => console.log('onNext:', x),
        e => {
            e.subscribe(function (value) {
                console.log('err', value);
            });
        },
        _ => console.log('onCompleted'));
```

Right now it works but I have to subscribe to the **e** in the error handler to get the value of the error thrown by dataStream. Is it possible to simplify this ?

updates:

I would like to code a "data-access routine" with resilience. Currently It will retry 3 times with a delay of 1sec and in the case of an error, It will throw the "error". The problem is it doesn't throw an error it throws a "Subject" and I have to subscribe to it to get the error.

```
let getPromiseStream = function (endpoint) {
    return Rx.Observable.
        just(endpoint).
        flatMap(requestUrl => {
            return _this.$http.get(requestUrl);
        });
};

let itemsStream = getPromiseStream('/items');
let locksStream = getPromiseStream('/error');
let usersStream = getPromiseStream('/users');
let favsStream = getPromiseStream('/favs');

let dataStream = Rx.Observable.
            zip(
            itemsStream,
            locksStream,
            usersStream,
            favsStream,
            (items, locks, users, favs) => {
                return {items: items.data, locks: locks.data, users: users.data, favs: favs.data};
            });
```

Comment: What is it you are trying to accomplish? The `retryWhen` method is for determining criteria for which the source `Observable` should continue retrying, why would you want those as part of the source stream?

Comment: I am new to Rxjs (FYI). The way I am looking at it, I am throwing an error at some point and I would like to catch it from my "main" error handler. I (think) I understand why "retryWhen" generates a "Subject". But is there a way to throw the error back onto the main stream ?
I will update my question with more details, thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`retryWhen` can be a little difficult to use (I had to look it up again to remember its behavior). Essentially `retryWhen` will take all errors that you receive from the source `Observable` and convert them into `onNext` calls. The function you pass in takes in *that* Observable and then lets you play with the events passing through. If you want to continue retrying it should simply pass the event through. If it should error then you need to convert the `onNext` into a `onError` or if you just want it to stop trying then you should convert it into an `onCompleted`.

So onto your code you want to delay a certain number of times and then error the whole thing out if it really is more than just a transient network error.

```
dataStream.
    retryWhen(errors => {
        return errors
            .flatMap((err, count) => {
              return count < 3 ? 
                //This will just get flattened out and passed through
                Rx.Observable.just(err) :
                //If you have received 3 errors it is time to throw
                //This error will get passed all the way to the final
                //onError method if it isn't caught along the way
                Rx.Observable.throw(err);
            })
            .delay(1000);
    })
    .subscribe(
        x => console.log('onNext:', x),
        e => console.log('err', value),
        _ => console.log('onCompleted'));
```

Additional note: I would suggest that you put the `retryWhen` on each `Observable` that feeds into your `zip` rather than on the whole thing. As in the latter case a failure from one will retry *all* the source `Observables` not just the one that failed.